# How do I automatically run rules when Outlook opens or a quick way of running rules

Tags: email, outlook

I have a bunch of rules setup on an IMAP account. I understand the difference between server side and client side rules and Exchange/IMAP accounts.

What I would like to know if I can setup Outlook 2010 to automatically run all rules when it opens.

The issue is that I have the emails opened on other devices etc. So when Outlook opens I wish all the client side rules to be run on the relevant Inbox to move the emails to the appropriate folders.

I would either like all the rules to run when Outlook opens or a quick and simple click option to run all outlook setup client side rules. Is this possible at all?

At present I would have to go to Rules > Manage Rules > Run rules now... > select all > include subfolders > run now. Its a bit tedious.